# Loading bitmaps efficiently from internal storage, not resource

Tags: android, performance, memory, bitmap

I'm downloading bitmaps like this:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
...
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

And saving them to internal storage like this:

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
```

But after studying the [google page about bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html), it says that downloading a large bitmap into memory might throw an outOfMemory exception, so I should scale this bitmap to occupy a much smaller space on the memory. The problem is that the code on the page only explains how to do it with resource images, not images from **internal storage**. So, I have two questions:

How to do it for a bitmap from internal storage?

And

Is there a way to download and save the image all in one way?

I'm first creating a Bitmap image and then passing it to the the method that will save it, so I assume that the image is being loaded entirely into the memory and then it's being saved to the internal storage.

Comment: Throw away BitmapFactory. Indead you should make a loop where you read chunks from the input stream and write them directly to the file output stream.

Comment: You are talking about 'internal memory' but we cannot see on 'filePath' if that comes true.

Comment: It does not look as a problem of loading bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

Loading images from internal memory isn't a problem, unless you load a lot all at once like in a ViewPager. Or your image is really really large. But if those aren't the case, you should be fine.

Regarding downloading images, I highly suggest that you not opt to go "all in one way." Because Object Oriented Programming. Also, try using **Volley** to download your images.

Comment: I'm loading them from internal storage but they're like 800x600 images to fit into 50x50 circular image views for messages, just like gmail, so I really should process them. Isn't there a simple way to write the images in parts without using Volley? I really needed a small solution for this. I think that for the bitmap processing is solved, I didn't see that a method decodeFile existed, I thought it was only decodeResource https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String)

Comment: @Gatonito actually what you really need to do is calculate sample size.
Here, https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the code belows:

```
public void loadPhotoToView(String path) {
        File imgFile = new File(path);
        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(imgFile));
        }
    }

    // Decode image and scale it to reduce memory consumption
    public Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // The new size we want to scale to, the bigger the better of quality
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE &&
                    o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Another way is use a library like Picasso to load image:

```
Picasso.with(this).load(imgFile).into(imageView);
```